# Gitlab ci pass pipeline_id from one child pipeline to another

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is there a way to pass the `pipeline_id` of one child pipeline to another child pipeline?
[image]

Comment: Maybe add your (or an example .gitlab-ci.yml) to show what you want. or if you solved it share your solution.